# Game gets slower after restart

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a game using Xcode, and it's working well with the exception of one problem. Every time I hit the restart button after the game over scene is presented, I lose frames. I have scoured the internet in search of a solution, but have found nothing. I've even used instruments to try and locate the source of my problem, but the only problem I could find is at the beginning of the GameScene class file, which I assume attributes to the loss of FPS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you delete objects when you restart the game?  If not, then the reason is that the old objects are working with new ones, and they are slowing down